# How to make a skybox move with the player but not jump with them

Tags: game-engine

I have a pretty nice skybox, but it doesn't seem realistic that the player can get right next to it, so I want it to move with the player, but not jump with the player or rotate with the player.

Comment: (by jump I mean move in the Z axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to.  I just added a *Copy Location* object constraint

Comment: Useful tip:  to make a skybox more realistic, place a sun lamp on the sun